# Preventing/detecting leakage of client secrets inadvertantly sent via HTTP?

Tags: apache, security, https, monitoring

Let's say I have a website, call it `www.yoyodyne.com`, that has both "insecure" and "secure" content:

- Insecure content contains no secrets, and access via HTTP is allowed to any website user.
- Secure content contains customer secrets, and should only be accessed by authenticated, authorized users via HTTPS. When accessing secure content, a web client may both receive secrets from, and send secrets to the website.

Let's say further that `www.yoyodyne.com` is served by Apache, and that I attempt to ensure access security (in both directions) by asserting the `SSLRequireSSL` directive for Locations that contain secure content.

Now, finally, let's say that a web client sends a request containing a customer secret via HTTP rather than HTTPS, because *somehow* (see below) it got hold of a URL whose pathname component references secure content, but whose scheme (protocol) component is erroneously set to `http` rather than `https`.

**Question 1**: Given that the Apache server listens on both ports 80 and 443 of `www.yoyodyne.com`'s IP address (in order to be able to serve both insecure
and secure content), doesn't the customer's secret get leaked even
though the `SSLRequireSSL` directive ultimately causes the request to be rejected?

**Question 2**: If we assume that there's always some chance that a client might receive
and use a bad URL of the sort described above, is there any way to prevent this kind of leakage if I'm constrained to using a single domain name/IP
address for the site? (Clearly, I can avoid the issue if I serve only secure
content from, say, `secure.yoyodyne.com`, which resolves to an IP address different from that of `www.yoyodyne.com`, and at which no one is listening on port 80. But if the owner of `www.yoyodyne.com` is cheap and doesn't want to pay for a second IP address, and/or objects on aesthetic grounds, I'm stuck with the constraint.)

--

Now, in the case of `www.yoyodyne.com`, there are at least two ways in which a
web client might get hold of a bad URL of the sort described above:

- A bug in the code of the website itself causes it to embed the link
  in a page that it serves;
- Any one of a number of "partner" websites, each of which authenticates
  the user on behalf of `www.yoyodyne.com`, supplies the link via an iframe.

It's obviously the responsibility of the developers and maintainers of
all these websites to ensure that they write no such bad links. But just as
obviously, there can be no guarantees. (While I may have some level of assurance about the behavior of `www.yoyodyne.com` by enforcing good coding standards and QA practices, I have no effective control over how the developers of the partner sites run their shops.)

So:

**Question 3**: Assuming (as above) that I don't have a separate `secure.yoyodyne.com`
site (to completely prevent the transmission of any such bad requests over
HTTP), what's the simplest, most effective mechanism I can deploy to notify
the `www.yoyodyne.com` adminstrator as soon as possible after such a bad request
is made? (Off the top of my head I'm imagining something like Nagios
monitoring the server logs and sending an alert when it sees such a bad access, but quite possibly there's a simpler way I haven't thought of.)

Comment: Where is this secret information? In the URL, in POST data, or on the returned page?

Comment: In the cases that this question concerns, either the URL's query component, or in POST data. In the scenario I've laid out, SSLRequireSSL should (I'm pretty sure) prevent exposure of any secrets in returned pages -- because they won't be returned.

Comment: Then the only way to prevent this is to close port 80.